# python fabric: put() results in permission denied

Tags: python, fabric

I use fabric and have:

```
put('/projects/configuration-management/prototype','/etc/nginx/sites-available')
```

The result is:

```
Underlying exception:
    Permission denied

Aborting.
```

Other configuration files can be uploaded easily. How could I avoid my issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need super user permission, run it using `sudo` and it will work just fine

In the docs ([link here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/operations.html)) says:

> While the SFTP protocol (which put uses) has no direct ability to
>   upload files to locations not owned by the connecting user, you may
>   specify **use_sudo=True** to work around this. When set, this setting
>   causes put to upload the local files to a temporary location on the
>   remote end (defaults to remote user’s $HOME; this may be overridden
>   via temp_dir), and then use sudo to move them to remote_path.

Comment: How do I add sudo to the put() function in fabric? I could not find it in the docs.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with latest version Fabric2